# Could not find signature for add_intercept: <DataFrame>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dask

Trying to do logisticregression with Dask but get the error

```
Could not find signature for add_intercept: <DataFrame>"
```

my code:

```
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
from dask_ml.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from dask_ml.datasets import make_classification

dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df2,chunksize=50)
dask_df.head()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df2[features], df2[label], test_size = 0.20, random_state = 42)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr.decision_function(X_test)
```